# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when writing xlsx using jxls

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jxls

1. Here are the APIs which I used for writing into EXCEL(.xlsx)

   poi  3.9
   poi-ooxml  3.9
   jxls-core  1.0.2
2. Here is my source code

   ```
   public ByteArrayOutputStream retrieveFinalReport() {

   InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()  
       .getResourceAsStream("Template_Name");  
   try {  
       workbook = transformer.transformXLS(is, beans);  
   } catch (final InvalidFormatException e) {  
       LOG.warn("Error Ocurred", e);  
   }  
   try {   
       workbook.write(outPutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream());  
   } catch (final IOException e) {  
       LOG.warn("Error Ocurred", e);  
   }  
   return outPutStream;
   ```
3. It works perfectly for files which are small in size.(Less than 1 MB size .xlsx files)
4. For the larger files, it throws OOM error.

**PS: Earlier we used templates which are .xls and able to write all the files.**

Highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use SXSSF.

Check out this link : [How to use Horrible SpreadSheet Format(HSSF) API](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html)

Code from the above link

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
        Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
        for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 1000; rownum++){
            Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
            for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++){
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
                String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
                cell.setCellValue(address);
            }

        }

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/temp/sxssf.xlsx");
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();

        // dispose of temporary files backing this workbook on disk
        wb.dispose();
}
```

Instead of `address` input your data

Comment: Thank you all. I have a question. Can't I use template with SXSSF instead of creating Rows n Cells n times?

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to JXLS-2 which has a support for SXSSF processing.
Then the code may look like this

```
 Transformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createSxssfTransformer(workbook, 100, false);
 AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
 List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
 Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
 xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context);
```

If you do not need formula processing (which is very limited in SXSSF support) you should disable it with

```
context.getConfig().setIsFormulaProcessingRequired(false);
```

See SxssfDemo class in [jxls-demo project](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
-XX:NewRatio=<factor> (try it with 2)
```

or

```
-XX:NewSize=<value>m
```

to raise the size of your young generation GC and be able to load bigger files.